# Statistics of dataframe grouped by two elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

To determine the statistics of a [pandas dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) group I found an explanation by [Chris Albon](http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_apply_operations_to_groups.html) that I want to apply to a dataframe grouped by two elements ("a" and "b" in this MWE).

So here is a function to calculate some group statistics:

```
def get_group_stats(group):
    return {'count': group.count().add_prefix('count_'),
            'mean': group.mean().add_prefix('mean_'),
            'sum': group.sum().add_prefix('sum_')}
```

Definition of a dataframe `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'a':['A','A','B','B','B','C'],
                    'b':['A','A','B','A','B','A'],
                    'c':[ 1, 2, 5, 5, 4, 6 ]})
```

Then create the statistics table grouped by "a" and "b":

```
s1 = df.groupby(['a', 'b']).apply(get_group_stats)
```

But the proposed `unstack()` function does not merge the dataframes correct. What I do want:

```
    a    |    b    | count_c | mean_c  | sum_c
-------------------------------------------------
    A    |    A    |    2    |   1.5   |   3.0
    B    |    A    |    1    |   5.0   |   5.0
    B    |    B    |    2    |   4.5   |   9.0
    C    |    B    |    1    |   6.0   |   6.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need return `Series` with `apply`:

```
def get_group_stats(group):
    return pd.Series({'count': group.c.count(),
                      'mean': group.c.mean(),
                      'sum': group.c.sum()})


s1 = df.groupby(['a', 'b']).apply(get_group_stats).add_suffix('_c')
print (s1)
     count_c  mean_c  sum_c
a b                        
A A      2.0     1.5    3.0
B A      1.0     5.0    5.0
  B      2.0     4.5    9.0
C A      1.0     6.0    6.0
```

But better is use [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) by `list` of functions:

```
s1 = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].agg(['count','mean','sum']).add_suffix('_c').reset_index()
print (s1)
   a  b  count_c  mean_c  sum_c
0  A  A        2     1.5      3
1  B  A        1     5.0      5
2  B  B        2     4.5      9
3  C  A        1     6.0      6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) for this:

```
In [1]: df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].agg(['count','mean','sum']).add_suffix('_c')

Out[1]: 
     count_c  mean_c  sum_c
a b                        
A A        2     1.5      3
B A        1     5.0      5
  B        2     4.5      9
C A        1     6.0      6
```

You could chain `reset_index()` too if you want `a` and `b` as columns and not index.

Comment: Elegant solution!  I added `.reset_index()`

Comment: @Api: @Jezrael aded this `agg` solution to his answer right after I posted. You should accept his answer, it's more complete.